# Event not caught when fired from rxJs subscribe onComplete callback

Tags: angular, rxjs, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I am receiving some data from a http request that I want to relay to the parent component via @Output and EventEmitter. My goal is to create a new item in a child component, and after it has been successfully stored on the backend, append an Id created on the backend, append it to the item in the frontEnd, and finally add it to the parent view.

I have tried calling *this.newItem.emit(item)* from inside the *.finally()* callback and the *.onComplete()*, aswell as we *onNext()*. In all cases the event has not been caught in the parent component, except for when I emitted the item right after the *.subscribe()* block

```js
child.ts
/* */
@Output() newItemEmitter= new EventEmitter();
/* */
saveItem() {
 let itemToView: {
  ... // A lot of data   
 };
 this.itemService.saveItem(item).subscribe(result => {
    itemToView = {
     ...
     Id: result.Data
    }
   }, error => {console.log(error)}
   , () => { console.log('Emitting!'); this.newItemEmitter.emit(itemToView) }
 }
 this.closeView() // Was not originally included. (1)
}
// this.newItemEmitter.emit(itemToView) // If emitting from  
// here, itemToView will not contain the right Id from the backend.
```

I have purposefully omitted some of the irrelevant html.

```html
parent.html
<ng-template  let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <fixed-item  (newItemEmitter)="addNewItemToView($event)" (closed)="closeAddNewItemTemplateView()">
  </fixed-item>
</ng-template>
```

```js
parent.ts
addNewItemToView($event) {
    console.log('Received event from child: ', $event)
    // Add to view here
}
```

My expected output is *Emitting!* followed by *Received event from child* but as of now, the only output is *Emitting!*.

**Edit:** (1): Removing *this.closeView()* solved the problem for me. I think the issue was that the event was aborted as the ng-template is closed.

Comment: make sure  you importing the eventemitter class from '@angular/core'.

Comment: It is imported. I am on Angular 5 if it makes any difference.

Comment: okay, i think "itemToView" is not in scope inside the function where it is getting emitted.

Comment: Changing to global scoping  _this.itemToView_ did no difference :(

Comment: Just my curiosity, have you tried using `Rxjs/Subject` instead of an EventEmitter?

Comment: Yeah, no luck :!

Comment: Emit from within the subscription block, right after itmeToView ends

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7cmsc

Your Same code works perfectly for me

Comment: Hey, I added the piece of code that was the culprit. As the child component is inside a template, the closing of said template somehow removed the event from the event-loop. Now I must figure out a different way of closing the template.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was when I called *this.closeView()* to close the component. Instead of closing the child component from the child itself, I now call the destroy method from the parent component. I believe that calling *this.closeView()* somehow removes emitted event from the event loop if the source of the event is in a *subscribe* callback.